# Illegal variable name csh script

Tags: lubuntu, csh

I need some help.I try to write csh script and I need to iterate through all files in current dir and do some tasks, so I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach f ($(ls))
    if( some condtions)
       echo "$f"
end
```

but every time I try to run this, I get: 
Illegal name error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to not be the whole script. The `if( some condtions)` won't run because `some condtions` is being interpreted as an unknown value, and not true or false.

Csh seems to be unfavorable by many, and I personally recommend bash.

Comment: I forgot to say, its get error with $(ls)

Comment: That looks like bash. In Csh, you'd do something like ```set thing="`ls`"```
If you want to use bash, then type in `bash`.